# How do i make it so it reads what the user says and uses it to make a role? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Okay so i want to make it so it questions you what role you want to name it, then you enter that and it says Type "?verify to gain Access to the Server!" ive currently got this but it does not work :/ need help

```
@bot.command()
async def verification(ctx, *args):
  guild = ctx.guild
  msg = ' '.join(args)
  def check(message):
    return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel and message.content.lower() == msg
  await ctx.send("What do you want to Name the Role?")
  await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60)
  await guild.create_role(name=msg, hoist=True, reason="Verification Role Creation", colour=discord.Colour(0x979c9f))
  await ctx.send("**Type ?verify to gain Access to the Server!**")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command's logic is incorrect:

1. It takes what you passing in args (`?verification test string` → `(test, string)`)
2. Checks for author, channel, and **string built from args is equal to message thats you wait for**.
3. You don't assign message you got anywhere.

I suggest do this in one of next ways:

- Use command args (`?verification Role Name` → *role* `Role Name` *created*)

  ```py
  @bot.command()
  async def verification(ctx, *, rolename: str): 
  """Create verification role""" 
  # first kwarg is "consume-rest" argument for commands: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments
      await ctx.guild.create_role(name=rolename, hoist=True, reason="Verification Role Creation", colour=discord.Colour(0x979c9f))
      await ctx.send("**Type ?verify to gain Access to the Server!**")
  ```
- Use actual message response (`?verification` → *Bot asks:* `What do you want to Name the Role?` → *User responses with (in example)* `Role Name` → *Role* `Role Name` *created*`

  ```py
  @bot.command()
  async def verification(ctx):
  """Create verification role"""
      def check(message):
          return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel
      await ctx.send("What do you want to Name the Role?")
      rolename = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60)
      await guild.create_role(name=rolename, hoist=True, reason="Verification Role Creation", colour=discord.Colour(0x979c9f))
      await ctx.send("**Type ?verify to gain Access to the Server!**")
  ```